# NSURLConnection scheduleInRunLoop 'leak'

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am POSTing form data asynchronously using NSURLConnection. Using instruments I can see that memory usage increases on starting the connection, but once the connection completes the memory usage drops to a level above the previous baseline. I refer to this as a 'leak' because approximately 60 seconds after the start/end of the connection, the memory is freed and the graph drops back to the original baseline.

Why is this memory being held on to for this time? How can I free it immediately?

```
- (id)initWithPostURL:(NSURL *)url content:(NSData *)content completionBlock:(void (^)(NSData *data))completionBlock boundary:(NSString *)boundary;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {        
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0f];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
        [urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", content.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:content];

        _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
        [_urlConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [_urlConnection start];
        _data = [NSMutableData data];
        _dataSemaphore = NULL;
        _completionBlock = completionBlock;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: you can use NSAutoreleasePool

Comment: It is wrapped in NSAutoreleasePool outside of this as it is called in a loop. I have confirmed that the pool drains, but this memory is not affected. It is as if the request is being held on to in some cache that remains for 60 seconds after the request completes.

Comment: The system uses a cache as well as a thread pool, so maybe that's why it takes a while before memory is released...